# Angular Material Tab control - RTL

Tags: angular, angular-material2

When applying RTL direction to [Angualr Material Tabs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview) control, [the animation breaks](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5tb5pj?file=app/tabs-overview-example.html) when toggling between tabs.

```
<div dir="rtl">
  <mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
</div>
```

Is there a known fix to this ?

[reproduce demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5tb5pj?file=app/tabs-overview-example.html)

Comment: which version of angular you are using?

Comment: angular 6 but it also occurred on angular 5.

Comment: I thought `dir` is the property of material but but its of HTML one, maybe `tabs` animation is not supported fully in this direction. not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was a bug indeed. it was fixed and merged to Master branch on github today (15 minutes ago at the time of this post).

https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/12215

Next major release will have this bug out of the way.
in the meanwhile you should use @moilkh's answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug probably, But you can fix it with this workaround for now.
set some css in your page:

```
.mat-tab-header{
direction:rtl;
}
.mat-tab-body-wrapper{
text-align:right
}
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5tb5pj-kpjplr)

Answer (score 2):

you need to put **dir** in **mat-tab-group** itself and container must be **ltr**

```
<div dir="ltr">
  <mat-tab-group  dir="rtl">
    <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you open an issue in GitHub in the [Angular Material](https://github.com/angular/material2) project looks like it is a bug. I tried your sample in Chrome and Edge browser and the issue with animation happens only in Chrome in Edge it works ok.

If you are can live without the animations you can use the `NoopAnimationsModule` instead of the `BrowserAnimationsModule` which removes all animations.